# Is there memory leak by using higher order javascript function like this?

Tags: memory-leaks

Assuming an api returns response that has products obj such as:

```
   response.products = [{
        id: 1,
        'productType': 'premium',
    }, {
        id: 2,
        'productType': 'premium',
    }, {
        id: 3,
        'productType': 'free',
    }];
   let filteredProducts = response.products.filter(p => p.productType === "premium");
   response.products = filteredProducts
```

Does reassigning filteredProducts to response.products creates memory leak? If yes, should I always delete response.product before reassigning new object to it?

```
let filteredProducts = response.products.filter(p => p.productType === "premium");
delete response.product; //do I need to delete old object so it doesn't become infant(no reference) in memory? 
response.products = newProducts
```

Comment: tldr; *no*, there is no "memory leak". As long as an object is _not strongly reachable_, it is eligible for collection.

Comment: The phrase "reassigning newProducts to original reference" probably is going down a misleading route. A *new* object (the result of the `filter`) is assigned to the `products` *property*. Per above the *old* object (which is no longer "named by" or "referenced" by the `products` property) can be reclaimed when it is no longer strongly reachable: given the example code, this occurs when the current scope (function) exits.